# Display from nested MySQL Select

Tags: php, mysql, select, nested

I'm running through a table with a loop to return all the results into a nice looking table.  It does so fine up until the subquery needs to execute.  The subquery looks at another table and uses the $office value from the starting loop to look up the information, from there it just totals up the integer value and assigns it to $paid.

For some reason both loops stop after it returns the first result and outputs $paid.  Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm doing?  I tried to wrap my head around this and it seems like I could hardcode the values and set individual variables for each result set, but that seems like a lot of work.  I just want to display the $paid integer for each result set it returns from the first loop.  Hopefully this all makes sense.  I greatly appreciate any advice given.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli ( $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name );
    $query = "select * from `drawer` where date(`date`) = '$mysql_date' order by `office`"; // select result set for selected date and order by office name
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {

echo "<tr class=table_border>\n"; //display results
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['office']."</td>\n"; // return office name
$office = $row['office']; // grab the office from the first loop to use it in the second loop
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['manager']."</td>\n"; // return manager name
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['scash']."</td>\n"; // display integer value
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['ecash']."</td>\n"; // display integer value

$newquery = "select * from `offer_det` where `office` = '$office' and date(date) = curdate()"; // subquery to display data from another table and insert for each row when the first loop starts
$resultquery = $mysqli->query($newquery);
while ($row=$resultquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $paid += $row['paid'];
}
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$paid."</td>\n"; // both loops end here
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['add']."</td>\n"; // should return integer value
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['remove']."</td>\n"; // should return integer
echo "<td class=table_rows nowrap width=10%>&nbsp;".$row['total']."</td>\n"; // should return integer
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `$row` into inner while loop

Change

```
while ($row=$resultquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $paid += $row['paid'];
}
```

To

```
while ($row1=$resultquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $paid += $row1['paid'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's allowing me to continue on with my loop.  Still not acting how I want it to, but I think I can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

you're assigning $row in the inner while loop - it's already assigned to the outer loop. Try changing it to a different variable name in the inner loop,

```
while ($row1=$resultquery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $paid += $row1['paid'];
}
```